# How to get a reference to an object by its full name in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

Let's say we have

```
package MyApp.foo

object Bar {
  def apply(x: Int) = x + 1
}
```

How to increase a value by means of this object using its full name ("MyApp.foo.Bar") string?

This functionality helped me to solve a task efficiently in C# and I miss it in Scala.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. Can you post the "equivalent" C# code where this technique is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want reflection. There's Java reflection, which is the only one available up to Scala 2.9.x, and Scala reflection, available since 2.10.0. I'm going to explain only the latter -- look up Java reflection for the former.

This is rather long, but you can look up Scala reflection elsewhere, or read [the docs here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). Alternatively, use [SMirror](https://github.com/fwbrasil/smirror), which is a wrapper around Scala reflection, providing a higher level.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val barSymbol = m staticModule "MyApp.foo.Bar"
val barType = barSymbol.typeSignature
val applySymbol = (barType declaration TermName("apply")).asMethod
val barMirror = m reflectModule barSymbol
val barInstance = barMirror.instance
val barInstanceMirror = m reflect barMirror.instance
val applyMirror = barInstanceMirror reflectMethod applySymbol
def increase(n: Int) = applyMirror.apply(n) match {
  case x: Int => Some(x)
  case _      => None
}
```